# How does setOut method change the value of System.out which is final in System class

Tags: java, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java: “final” System.out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951464/java-final-system-out)

Can someone please help me in understanding how the `setOut` method works?
It can change the current pipe lining of `System.out` from Monitor to PrintStream object, but how is it changing reference of out?

Answer (score 2):

`System#setOut` internally calls a native method to redirect `out`. In other words: *voodoo magic* ;)

Comment: Well done Can you please explain some more about voodoo magic and how setOut use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java is open source, let's have a look:

http://www.mavenjava.com/sun/jdk/1.6.0/src/java/lang/System.java.html#System.setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29

It calls out to a native method to set the output - the JVM basically bypasses the "final" check.

Comment: Paolo how can u prove that what u saying is right???
i mean do u have reasons to ur answer.

Comment: See the accepted answer in the duplicate question link