# System.setIn() reassigns final System.in

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java: "final" System.out, System.in and System.err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951464/java-final-system-out-system-in-and-system-err)

It's just occurred to me although I've done it so many times without paying attention: `System.setIn()` is reassigning static final `System.in`.

Am I missing something? How is it possible to reassign a final field.

Comment: @david: honestly looked for a while but this question didn't come up probably because it's referring to System.out

Comment: @dimitrisli - I have updated the title of the linked question to make it easier to find ... for when this question gets closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, final static fields may not be modified. However `System.in`, `System.out`, and `System.err` are **final static** fields that, for legacy reasons, *must be allowed to be changed* by the methods `System.setIn`, `System.setOut` and `System.setErr`. We refer to these fields as being write-protected to distinguish them from ordinary final fields.

The compiler needs to treat these fields differently from other final fields. For example, a read of an ordinary final field is "immune" to synchronization: the barrier involved in a lock or volatile read does not have to affect what value is read from a final field. Since the value of write-protected fields may be seen to change, synchronization events should have an effect on them. Therefore, the semantics dictate that these fields be treated as normal fields that cannot be changed by user code, unless that user code is in the System class.

EDIT: Worth to mention is that you can "hack" final fields and set its value by calling setAccessible(true) on them (or by using Unsafe methods). Such techniques are used during deserialization, by Hibernate and other frameworks, etc, but they have one limitation: code that have seen value of final field before modification is not guaranteed to see the new value after modification. **What's special about the 3 System fields is** that they are free of this limitation since ***they are treated in special way by the compiler***.

Comment: mmm.. special treatment by the JVM for legacy reasons. makes sense

Comment: give the reference if you are going to copy an entire section of java language spec, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5.4

Comment: It's worth noting that setAccessible(true) changes the private/public modifier to public. You actually have to go into the modifiers field and change the modifiers. You have to use reflection to obtain the modifiers, then use reflection to change the modifiers, as I recall. I haven't done it in a while -- last time I had to hack a final field was months ago and I just copypasta'd it.

Answer (score 3):

`System.setIn()` and its friends `setOut()` and `setErr()` all delegate to native methods, where Java access control rules are not enforced.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever did this and wasted a JLS section[1] explaining it,  are just being silly.

These fields should simply drop the `final` modifier. It doesn't break binary compatibility. [2]

Allowing user to write `System.out=x` isn't a problem; after all he can do `System.setOut(x)` anyway. Compiler needs a special handling to translate the 1st assignment to the 2nd method call. That is better than the current way, which twists *both* read and write semantics of `System.out`.

If we really don't want to see `System.out=x`, make it an exception so compiler won't compile it.

These 2 solutions are simple syntactic stuff; no need to break Java Memory Model for this silly little thing.

[1] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5.4

[2] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.4.9