# How does Tomcat redirect verbose:gc console output to catalina.out

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, logging

I need to understand how Tomcat is able to catch JVM garbage collection console output logs  and put it in catalina.out.

I tried to redirect *System.out* and *System.err*, but no can do. I was not able to get the output of GC logs.
However, when activating *-verbose:gc* in Tomcat (in catalina.sh, *JAVA_OPT*) and later cheking the output in *catalina.out* I was able to see the GC logs. How is this possible?
How was Tomcat able to redirect that output to a file?

Maybe do you know any way to redirect the GC log output inside some java application using java code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `java.lang.System.setErr(...)` and `java.lang.System.setOut(...)` ?

Comment: Yes, I used System.setErr() and System.setOut(). That does not work, the new out (or err source) is redirected, everything I write using System.out.print() is written in the file I use as out destination but when GC prints something it does not get trough the "out" variable (neither trough err as well) and ends up on console.

Comment: I should have looked more in depth in the catalina.sh. The startup command ends with `>> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"`, thus everything that appears in console is redirected to catalina.out .
Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with code; the `catalina.out` file is not a "real log", it's just a file into which the standard tomcat startup command pushes all it's output.

In other words, this is a shell question, not a java one :)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat must indeed be using System.setErr() and System.setOut(). There's a great discussion about how that works elsewhere on this site: [java: "final" System.out, System.in and System.err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951464/java-final-system-out-system-in-and-system-err)

Tomcat redirects all console output to catalina.out. You might be able to configure this via the JULI log settings.