# System.out could be set or not?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java: “final” System.out, System.in and System.err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951464/java-final-system-out-system-in-and-system-err)

Direct setting of `System.out`,

```
System.out = null; //gives error that it is final and that's understood
```

But have a look at this:

```
System.setOut(null); //allows to set out ??
```

But how is that possible if `out` is `final`?

Comment: It's a legacy thing.  The detailed and correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951464/java-final-system-out-system-in-and-system-err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that things that are written using native C, and especially library classes, don't necessarily have to play by the same rules as you and I writing pure Java.

**edit:** Upon further investigation, it turns out even you and I can change `final` fields (provided the security managed doesn't object). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/367273

Comment: its weird how we can break the semantics so easily, and all these are trick questions that can boggle anyone. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Its done on very low level. On `Java` level you cannot assign even `null` to `final` variable. Source code from JDK 1.7:

```
/**
 * Reassigns the "standard" output stream.
 *
 * <p>First, if there is a security manager, its <code>checkPermission</code>
 * method is called with a <code>RuntimePermission("setIO")</code> permission
 *  to see if it's ok to reassign the "standard" output stream.
 *
 * ...
 */
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
    checkIO();
    setOut0(out); //native method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance the static variable System.out is final so you cannot set it.

In the second instance you are calling a static method that will set standard output to a different stream.