# strange 'out' variable, System.out.println()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Following is the code from java.lang.System class (JDK version 1.6)

```
public final static PrintStream out = nullPrintStream(); //out is set to 'null'

private static PrintStream nullPrintStream() throws NullPointerException {
    if (currentTimeMillis() > 0) {
        return null;
    }
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

when we write `System.out.println("Something");` in our code then why don't we get NullPointerException even when 'out' is set to 'null'

Anyhow `out` will be set via following `setOut` method in System class

```
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
     checkIO();
     setOut0(out);
 }
```

Theyn why JLS needs `nullPrintStream` method ?

Comment: `if (currentTimeMillis() > 0) { return null; }` => that's really odd.. In JDK 7, it is simply: `public final static PrintStream out = null;`.

Comment: @assylias It's all there to placate the earlier versions of javac/JIT compilers. Without that `if` the compiler could realize it always returns `null` and compile `out` as a compile-time constant, with all the bad consequences.

Comment: This means that once enough time has passed to make the value of `currentTimeMillis()` overflow the maximum value for a `long`, all applications running with virtual machines older than Java 7, will fail with an error: `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException at java.lang.System.nullPrintStream(Unknown Source)` or similar.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951464/java-final-system-out-system-in-and-system-err

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the `private static void  initializeSystemClass()` - this method is called to start things up, it calls `setOut0()` which is a `native` method. This ties the `Stream` into where it's supposed to be.

So even though the field may *look* `public static final` it actually isn't, the `native` code changes it.

**EDIT**

OP asks *Then why JLS needs nullPrintStream method?*

This is to do with the java compiler - it will "inline" `static final` fields if they are assigned to something constant at compile time, like `null`. The compiler will actually replace each reference to the field with the constant.

This would break the initialisation as objects would no longer hold a reference to the `Stream` but to `null`. Assigning the stream to the return of a method prevents the inlining.

Some might call it a dirty hack. To misquote Bismarck "The JDK is like sausages, it's best not to see it being made".

Comment: Although as commented above, in Java 7 it has been rectified - so it has to do with older compilers as indicated by Marko.

Comment: They could have defined `public final static PrintStream out = null;`. Help to understand "lnline" static final field.

Comment: @AmitG take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173372/java-static-final-values-replaced-in-code-when-compiling) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9). If you define something as a compile time constant the (Java 6) compiler would use that information to optimise code - it would replace any references with the literal. So anything that said `System.out` would be replaced with `null` by the compiler as it assumes that `System.out` cannot change being as it is set to `null` and it is `final`.

Comment: +1 for a beautiful explanation. If I could - I would give +2 for the quote at the end :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just how the System.out class is intialised.

There is also a method:

```
 private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

Which is called in the following method:

```
private static void initializeSystemClass() {
```

Answer (score 2):

System.in, out, and err are managed by the JVM from native code. This whole magic with nullPrintStream() was there to keep javac from inlining these fields. Since java 7 it looks like

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```