# Why doesn't System.out return a null object?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, system, printstream

In System.java, `out` is instantiated by:

```
public final static PrintStream out = nullPrintStream();
```

You would expect this to return a valid `PrintStream` object, except this is what the method looks like:

```
private static PrintStream nullPrintStream() throws NullPointerException {
    if (currentTimeMillis() > 0) {
        return null;
    }
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

This will always return null. However, calling something like `System.out.println()` calls the `println()` method on a valid `PrintStream` object instead of throwing a null pointer exception. Can anyone explain why this works and how/where the `PrintStream` object is actually being instantiated?

Comment: Which version of Java are you talking about?  Be precise.

Comment: The code I was referencing was jdk 6-b14.

Comment: Yes, that post answers my question. My bad, this is a duplicate.

Comment: why the nullPrintStream? to work around inlining problem. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566079