# System.out is static, final. But it has a default value

Tags: java, system, final

If out is a static, final instance object, it must be initialized and cannot be modified.

But it having a default value (of say console) seems to imply the default can be modified. I am therefore confused by the final modifier here. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in more detail? It's not clear how having a default value implies that it can be modified. `final` keeps a variable from being ***re***assigned to.

Comment: The use of the word 'default' implies it can be assigned another value. How do I do this if the class is in java.lang?

Comment: Where are you seeing 'default'? Wherever it is, the wording is being misleading.

Comment: The fact that it has a value just means it was initialized, just like `private static final int fred = 3;` Your question isn't clear.

Comment: It is from Java- A Complete Reference Guide, Ninth Edition, p. 304. 'System.out refers to the standard output stream. By default this is the console.'

Comment: A better duplicate: [java: “final” System.out, System.in and System.err?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5951620/5221149)