# Separate Input And Output In Console In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse to run my java programs but there is a problem with Eclipse's console that the input and output appears in the same console. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = scan.nextInt();
        while(t-- > 0) {
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
```

For this code let the input be

```
2
3
4
```

then the output that i gets looks like

```
2
3
43

4
```

Is there any way to get separate input and output and get the distinction in eclipse.

Comment: Any reaction regarding my answer?

Answer (score 1):

One could re-assign `System.in` and/or `System.out` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951464/java-final-system-out-system-in-and-system-err).

Of course, this is not Eclipse-specific solution but a Java one.

I would be working with files in first place.